# invalid url error with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I just started a project with phonegap and I m getting a "invalid url error" message box + app crash on a html link to "http://maps.google.fr" (external link)  , It works without problem on IPhone..

any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest code has the new white-list feature. If you are referencing external hosts, you will have to add the host in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key. Wildcards are ok. So if you are connecting to "http://phonegap.com", you have to add "phonegap.com" to the list (or use the wildcard "*.phonegap.com" which will match subdomains as well).

Comment: but then how to actuall call the url from java script navigator.app.loadUrl('http://google.com'); is NOT working